# every link always make ajaxy request although it's not declare as ajaxy class

Tags: ajax, jquery

i've many link in my page, and if i clicked a link from ajaxy class for 1st time, it will make a request

the 2nd times when i click another link that's not an ajaxy class, it will make a same request and causing some error in firebug, but it's not seen in client browser ..

the 3rd times when i clicked the link from ajaxy class, it will redirected to another page, not make an ajaxy request for load the page into my content ..

here it's my code

in my first div

```
<div class="block">
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="odd"><a href="./index.php/aaa/bbb/ccc/first" class="ajaxy ajaxy-page">First</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

my second div

```
<div class="block">
<ul id="navigation1">
<li class="odd"><a href="./index.php/aaa/bbb/ccc/second" class="other">Second</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and my main content for show the result from the request

```
<div id="maincol">
<div id="result">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="current" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
</div>
```

and the code for create ajaxy request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        var $body = $(document.body),
            $menu = $('#navigation'),
            $content = $('#content'),
            $current = $('#current');

        $.Ajaxy.configure({
            'method': 'get',
            'Controllers': {
                '_generic': {
                    request: function(){
                        var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy;
                        if ( Ajaxy.options.debug ) window.console.debug('$.Ajaxy.Controllers._generic.request', [this,arguments]);
                        $body.addClass('loading');
                        return true;
                    },
                    response: function(){
                        var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy; var data = this.State.Response.data; var state = this.state||'unknown';
                        if ( Ajaxy.options.debug ) window.console.debug('$.Ajaxy.Controllers._generic.response', [this,arguments], data, state);
                        var title = data.title||false; // if we have a title in the response JSON
                        if ( !title && this.state||false ) title = 'jQuery Ajaxy - '+this.state; // if not use the state as the title
                        if ( title ) document.title = title; // if we have a new title use it
                        $body.removeClass('loading');
                        $('#current').text('Our current state is: ['+state+']');
                        return true;
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy; var data = this.State.Error.data||this.State.Response.data; var state = this.state||'unknown';
                        var error = data.error||data.responseText||'Unknown Error.';
                        var error_message = data.content||error;
                        window.console.error('$.Ajaxy.Controllers._generic.error', [this, arguments], error_message);
                        $body.removeClass('loading');
                        $('#current').text('Our current state is: ['+state+']');
                        return true;
                    }
                },

                'page': {
                    classname: 'ajaxy-page',
                    matches: /^\/index.php\/?/,
                    request: function(){
                        var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy;
                        if ( Ajaxy.options.debug ) window.console.debug('$.Ajaxy.Controllers.page.request', [this,arguments]);
                        $menu.find('.active').removeClass('active');
                        $content.stop(true,true).fadeOut(400);
                        return true;
                    },
                    response: function(){
                        var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy; var data = this.State.Response.data; var state = this.state; var State = this.State;
                        if ( Ajaxy.options.debug ) window.console.debug('$.Ajaxy.Controllers.page.response', [this,arguments], data, state);
                        $menu.children(':has(a[href*="'+State.raw.state+'"])').addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
                        var Action = this;
                        $content.html(data.content).fadeIn(400,function(){
                            Action.documentReady($content);
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```